# Php sum numbers with the same string

Tags: php, sum

i try sum numbers with the same string , for get one only number to the end , for example this :

```
<?php
$result.="1";
$result.="4";
$result.="8";
$result.="346";

$end +=result;

echo $end;
?>
```

I try do this but no get never the result ok , only show all numbers but not the result of the sum , by this my question , i don´t know if i writte something bad or similar

Thank´s for the help , regards

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating instead of adding.

```
<?php
$result+=1;   // Need the += here instead of .=
$result+=4;
$result+=8;
$result+=346;

$end +=result; // Like you already did here.

echo $end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add up STRINGs not INTs.  You have to convert the values.

```
$result+=intval("1");
$result+=intval("4");
$result+=intval("8");
$result+=intval("346");

$end =$result;

echo $end;
```

Comment: PHP will do type juggling for you - there's no need for `intval` here. If you perform addition on a string, PHP will attempt to convert it into a number for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you are supposed to do it, if you really want to store every number, just use an array :

```
<?php
$myNumber = [];
$myNumber[] = 1;
$myNumber[] = 4;

$sum = 0;
foreach($myNumber as $r) 
    $sum += $r;

echo $sum;
?>
```

$sum will now contain the sum of every number. You could also use the array_sum function to perform this operation.